# Auditability in SAML 2.0

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

Is SAML 2.0 capable of storing all the users that are accessing my API-REST and this way I can keep track of the people that are entering my API? 
For example, if I want to know who accessed to my Api yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SAML` is only the format in which your users' information arrives. e.g. using [the examples](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php), the following is how a user may be represented in `SAML`:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="eduPersonAffiliation" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">users</saml:AttributeValue>
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">examplerole1</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
```

The `uid` attribute would be their username along with their email address in the `mail` attribute. `eduPersonAffiliation` says what relationship they have to their organisation. In this case they are a user with a role of examplerole1 in their own organisation.

`SAML` does not record this beyond delivering it to your API. It would be up to you to extract these attributes and create your own auditing system from them.

A lot of `SAML` Identity Providers (IdP) release eduPerson attributes. The latest schema is [here](https://wiki.refeds.org/display/STAN/eduPerson+2020-01).

Comment: In your answer, @codebrane, I think you've gone beyond the needs of OP, and that muddles the answer. I think the answer is there, you've just hidden it inside of information that OP doesn't need.

Comment: essentially, the answer is "no saml doesn't provide auditing" but this is the stuff you can use to do it yourself